# Send message with Telegram API and store session (NOT with bot API)

Tags: java, android, session, telegram, sendmessage

I want to implement a very simple Java Telegram Client, which is capable of sending and receiving messages and store the sessions across multiple starts. I already managed to authenticate and receive messages

```
api = new TelegramApi(apiState, new AppInfo(API_ID, "console", "1", "1", "en"), new ApiCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthCancelled(TelegramApi api) {
                Log.d(TAG, "-----------------CANCELLED----------------");
                Log.d(TAG, api.getApiContext().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdatesInvalidated(TelegramApi api) {
                Log.d(TAG, "-----------------INVALIDATED----------------");
                Log.d(TAG, api.getApiContext().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(TLAbsUpdates tlAbsUpdates) {
                Log.d(TAG, "-----------------UPDATE----------------");
                Log.d(TAG, tlAbsUpdates.toString());
                if (tlAbsUpdates instanceof TLUpdateShortMessage) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "-----------------UPDATE CHAT MESSAGE----------------");
                    int senderId = ((TLUpdateShortMessage) tlAbsUpdates).getUserId();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Message from " + senderId);
                    String message = ((TLUpdateShortMessage) tlAbsUpdates).getMessage();
                    Log.d(TAG, message);
                    activity.appendMessage(TAG, message);
                }
            }
        });
        api.switchToDc(2);
        TLConfig config = null;
        try {
            config = api.doRpcCallNonAuth(new TLRequestHelpGetConfig());
        } catch (TimeoutException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        apiState.updateSettings(config);
```

However, I struggle to send messages to another user. For the beginning, it would be enough if I could send a message back to the user, who sent me a message before (by retrieving the senderId, as you can see in the onUpdate method before). However, if someone could also help me with retrieving the ids of my saved contacts, it would be perfect.

Furthermore, I want to store the sessions accross multiple startups, since I get a FLOOD_WAIT error (420), if I test my code to often.

For this I used https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi/blob/51713e9b6eb9e0ae0d4bbbe3d4deffff9b7f01e4/src/main/java/org/telegram/bot/kernel/engine/MemoryApiState.java and its used classes (e.g. TLPersistence), which stores and loads the ApiState. However, apparently it does not store the signin status, since I always have to authenticate my number every time I update the code.
By the way, I am using Api layer 66 (https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi/releases).

**UPDATE 1:**
Problems with sending messages solved myself:

```
private void sendMessageToUser(int userId, String message) {
        TLInputPeerUser peer = new TLInputPeerUser();
        peer.setUserId(userId);
        TLRequestMessagesSendMessage messageRequest = new TLRequestMessagesSendMessage();
        messageRequest.setFlags(0);
        messageRequest.setPeer(peer);
        messageRequest.setRandomId(new SecureRandom().nextLong());
        messageRequest.setMessage(message);
        api.doRpcCallNonAuth(messageRequest, 1500, new RpcCallback<TLAbsUpdates>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(TLAbsUpdates tlAbsUpdates) {
                Log.d(TAG, "-----------------------MESSAGE SENT-----------------------");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int i, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "-----------------------MESSAGE SENT ERROR-----------------------");
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(i));
                if(s != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

However, now I am stuck at finding the userIds of my contacts.

After first update this is left:

- Saving the session state (and signin state)
- Find userIds of contacts

**Update 2:**
I managed to fetch the users, with which there are already dialogs. This is enough for my use case, however, loading all contacts would be perfect. This is how to load users from existing dialogs:

```
 private int getUserId(String phone) throws InterruptedException {
        TLRequestMessagesGetDialogs dialogs = new TLRequestMessagesGetDialogs();
        dialogs.setOffsetId(0);
        dialogs.setLimit(20);
        dialogs.setOffsetPeer(new TLInputPeerUser());
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        api.doRpcCallNonAuth(dialogs, 1500, new RpcCallback<TLAbsDialogs>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(TLAbsDialogs tlAbsDialogs) {
                Log.d(TAG, "----------------------getUsers--------------------");
                for(TLAbsUser absUser : ((TLDialogs) tlAbsDialogs).getUsers()) {
                    users.add((TLUser) absUser);
                }
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int i, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "----------------------getUsers ERROR--------------------");
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        latch.await();
        for(TLUser user : users) {
            if(user.getPhone().equals(phone)) {
                return user.getId();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

After second update this is left:

- Saving the session state (and signin state)
- Get user ids from contacts instead of dialogs